# Controlling the input language keyboard programatically from the android app.

Tags: android

The problem is that when I change the language of my android device to Hindi, it changes the keyboard  to Hindi as well.But I want that the app should appear in Hindi but English keyboard should always open inside the app.I want that it should be done programatically through the app instead of changing the devive settings.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Android has restricted this for security reasons. If you can manipulate the input method, you can do things like key logging, hence tampering privacy. You could however use the `InputManager` and let the user select an input method:

```
InputMethodManager ime=(InputMethodManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if(ime!=null) {
                   ime.showInputMethodPicker();
                }
```

But the above code will only show the active keyboard set the user in Settings.